# Join two tables on specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help in joining two tables with a specific condition. I want to left join Table_1 with Table_2 on the nearest Table_A.Col_A <= Table.Col_B

So I have two tables

```
Table_1
Col_A
1
2
6 

Table_2
Col_A | Col_B
1     | p1
4     | p2
5     | p3

Result Table
Col_A | Col_B
1     | p1
2     | p1
6     | p3
```

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery handles this:

```
select t1.col_a,
       (select t2.col_b
        from table2 t2
        where t2.col_A <= t1.col_A
        order by t2.col_A desc
        limit 1
       )
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: Now I get the error 
    Correlated scalar subqueries must be aggregated

Comment: @sks27 . . . That error makes no sense.  MySQL (and almost every other database) supports correlated subqueries like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM Table_1 t1 JOIN Table_2 t2 on t1.col1 <= t2.col1
WHERE --something matches
```

However there is not much information on this post, the more details you can provide should allow us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the condition in the ON clause like this:

```
select 
  t1.Col_A, t2.Col_B 
from Table_1 t1 left join Table_2 t2
on t2.Col_A = (select max(Col_A) from Table_2 where Col_A <= t1.Col_A)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tWnb3NxdvLpcejcq1UEwWb/0).
Results:

```
| Col_A | Col_B |
| ----- | ----- |
| 1     | p1    |
| 2     | p1    |
| 6     | p3    |
```